# Can't find logical fault in script which should execute a tcpdump

Tags: shell-script, kill

I have written a script which compares the time and if it is the same start time like the current time and not like the end time it starts a tcpdump. And If the end time is like the current time it searches the PID and kills it. But I think there is still a logical fault in it, but I don't really know how to solve it.

```
Code:
#!/bin/sh
source /media/usbhd-sd[b-d]1/config.conf
pluggedin=true
echo $TIMESTART
echo $TIMEEND
echo $$
echo $Zeit
echo $$ >> /tmp/test.txt
while [ $pluggedin ];do
        Zeit=$(date +"%T")
        if [[ $TIMESTART == $Zeit ]];then
                if [[ $TIMEEND != $Zeit ]] && [ "$(pidof tcpdump)" == "" ];then
                        echo "tcpdump started"
                        sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]1/abfrage2.pcap &
                        #sudo umount /dev/sdb1
                else
                        pid1=$(ps -eo pid,args|awk '/abfrage2/ && ! /awk/{print $1}')
                        echo $pid1 >> /tmp/test.txt
                        sudo kill $pid1
                        echo "autodump stopped"
                fi

        else
        echo "tcpdump not yet started"
        fi
done
```

I already debugged it and it gives me this output when the first if is right, but when the first if isn't right is also doesn't check the inner if. Would it work if I check for the PID and the do an or in the outer if?

```
Code:
+ [ true ]
+ date +%T
+ Zeit=08:51:00
+ [[ 08:51:00 == 08:51:00 ]]
+ [[ 08:51:02 != 08:51:00 ]]
+ pidof tcpdump
+ [ 9945 ==  ]
+ awk /abfrage2/ && ! /awk/{print $1}
+ ps -eo pid,args
+ pid1=
+ echo
+ sudo kill -9
kill: you need to specify whom to kill
+ echo autodump stopped
autodump stopped
```

**Update**

I found some faults by myself

That's the most recent code. It's working almost now, but the tcpdump still doesn't get killed. But it's already writing data into the file.

```
    #!/bin/sh
source /media/usbhd-sd[b-d]1/config.conf
pluggedin=true
echo $TIMESTART
echo $TIMEEND
echo $$
echo $Zeit
echo $$ >> /tmp/test.txt
while [ $pluggedin ];do
        Zeit=$(date +"%T")
        if [[ $TIMESTART == $Zeit ]] || [[ "$pid1" != "" ]];then
                if [[ $TIMEEND != $Zeit ]];then
                        if [ "$pid1" == "" ];then
                                echo "tcpdump started"
                                sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]1/abfrage2.pcap &
                                pid1=$(ps -eo pid,args|awk '/abfrage2/ && ! /awk/{print $1}')
                                #sudo umount /dev/sdb1
                        else
                        echo "Tcpdump already running"
                        fi
                else
                        if [ "$pid" != ""];then
                                echo $pid1 >> /tmp/test.txt
                                sudo kill -9 $pid1
                                echo "autodump stopped"
                        else
                                echo "autodump already stopped"
                        fi
                fi

        else
        echo "tcpdump noch yet started"
        fi
done
```

Now I get this output through debugging. When the time is on 40s the PID isn't available :

```
+ [ true ]
+ date +%T
+ Zeit=10:45:39
+ [[ 10:45:30 == 10:45:39 ]]
+ [[ 30285 !=  ]]
+ [[ 10:45:40 != 10:45:39 ]]
+ [ 30285 ==  ]
+ echo Tcpdump already running
Tcpdump already running
+ [ true ]
+ date +%T
+ Zeit=10:45:40
+ [[ 10:45:30 == 10:45:40 ]]
+ [[ 30285 !=  ]]
+ [[ 10:45:40 != 10:45:40 ]]
+ [  != ]
sh: !=: argument expected
+ echo autodump already stopped
autodump already stopped
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question, good examples, good data, good effort, thank you.

Since the time is always changing, you should use time values than can be more easily compared.  Use the `date` command to change all of the time values to the number of seconds since the "epoch" (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

```
timestart=$(date +%s -d "$TIMESTART")
timeend=$(date +%s -d "$TIMEEND")
```

Use the same format in `Zeit`, now you can compare the dates as integers, most recent is larger:

```
        Zeit=$(date +"%s")
        if [ $timestart -le $Zeit ];then
                if [ $timeend -le $Zeit ] && [ "$(pidof tcpdump)" == "" ];then
```

I also see that you appear to be attempting to kill the background `tcpdump`. You might consider using the builtin `$!` variable, which contains the PID of the most recently started background job, for example (all code in this answer is untested):

```
unset tcpdump_pid
while [ $pluggedin ];do
        Zeit=$(date +"%s")
        if [ $timestart -le $Zeit ] && [ "$tcpdump_pid" == "" ]; then
                echo "tcpdump started"
                sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]1/abfrage2.pcap &
                tcpdump_pid=$$
        fi                            
        if [ $timeend -le $Zeit ] && [ "$tcpdump_pid" != "" ];then
                sudo kill $tcpdump_pid
        fi
        # sleep ?
done
```

According to the `tcpdump` man page, either the SIGINT or SIGTERM will terminate `tcpdump`, so the `-9` is unnecessary and should not be used.  The `kill` default of SIGTERM will suffice.

Comment: So I deleted the -9 but It's still not running properly, can you quickly check the updated code?

Comment: Check what?  You only took out `-9`?  You didn't change the way you calculate and compare time. You didn't change the way you keep track of the `pid`.  I don't know what to check.  It's not going to work because you  check  for equal to specific times. After those times pass, the script won't do what you want.  You have to convert the time `$(date +%s -d "$TIMESTART")` so you can compare time values for less-than (`-lt`) or less-than-or-equal (`-le`) _not_ equality (`==` or `!=`).